# Regex to find special pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string to parse. First I have to check if string contains special pattern:

1. I wanted to know if there is substrings  which starts with "$(", 
   and end with ")",
2. and between those start and end special strings,there should not be
   any white-empty space,
3. it should not include "$" character inside it.

I have a little regex for it in C#

```
 string input = "$(abc)";
 string pattern = @"\$\(([^$][^\s]*)\)";
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
 foreach (var match in matches)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("value = " + match);
 }
```

It works for many cases but failed at input= $(a$() , which inside the expression is empty. I wanted NOT to match when input is $().[ there is nothing between start and end identifiers].

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: Did you use just `string input = "$()";` or did you put something else after that?

Comment: sorry the failed input is = $(a$() where between $( AND ) thereis $ which is against to my rules

Comment: Well, you should merge the negated classes `[^$]` and `[^\s]`, and I pointed out another possible problem with the regex, since I don't know the nature of your input in my answer.

Comment: The input is any string[ numeric, alphabetic, special strings etc] which may contains white spaces

Comment: Well, my answer was the last one, but it is the only one that would match `abc` in `$(abc)(something)` whilst the others will match `abc)(something`, and if it can contain anything, I'll keep my assumption that you can have back to back parens as demonstrated in my answer, which can cause some problems.

Comment: Misunderstanding but it correctly fits my purpose...$(def)$()$(abc)(something) should find abc and def.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex does *not* match `$()` because the `[^$]` matches at least 1 character. The only way I can think of where you would have this match would be when you have an input containing more than one parens, like:

```
$()(something)
```

In those cases, you will also need to exclude at least the closing paren:

```
string pattern = @"\$\(([^$\s)]+)\)";
```

The above matches for example:

- `abc` in `$(abc)` and
- `abc` and `def` in `$(def)$()$(abc)(something)`.

Answer (score 3):

Note: `[^$]` matches a single character but not of `$`

Use the below regex if you want to match `$()`

```
\$\(([^\s$]*)\)
```

Use the below regex if you don't want to match `$()`,

```
\$\(([^\s$]+)\)
```

- `*` repeats the preceding token zero or more times.
- `+` Repeats the preceding token one or more times.

Your regex `\(([^$][^\s]*)\)` is wrong. It won't allow `$` as a first character inside `()` but it allows it as second or third ,, etc. See the demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/nF1wX0/1). You need to combine the negated classes in your regex inorder to match any character not of a space or `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace the * with a +  and merge the options.

```
string pattern = @"\$\(([^$\s]+)\)";
```

+ means 1 or more

* means 0 or more